# VBA: USerform - How to create a userform based on some Checkbox selected

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to create a Userform2 with some text boxes and a proceed button? Userform 2 will be created based on the values selected (Checkboxes) from another userfomr1.

Example 1 - user select all the fields

[image]

Userform2 will be created based on the values selected from Userfomr1.

[image]

Comment: From a user perspective, I would rather just be presented with a fully-loaded screen 2 and then have the option to leave any fields blank that I wasn't interested in.  It seems ridiculous (to me anyway) to have to go through another form first.  But that's just my personal opinion, and everyone always tells me I am weird, so other people may have different views.

Comment: Your answer is "Yes, it's possible". But that wasn't really the question, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mimic these UserForms structure to have working example:
[Userform1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsKOp.jpg) 
[UserForm2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21tTB.jpg)

As you have mentioned that you are new to macros, watch for appropriate Names of controls: TextBox1,TextBox2...CheckBox1,CheckBox2..., CommandButton1_Click....ect

so code below will work with your forms.

Create new module and paste this code:

```
Sub formAction()
' set them to invisible first, it can be done in control properties also.
UserForm2.TextBox1.Visible = False
UserForm2.TextBox2.Visible = False
UserForm2.TextBox3.Visible = False
UserForm2.TextBox4.Visible = False

UserForm2.TextBox4.Left = 10 'example of controls movement
UserForm2.TextBox4.Top = 10 'example of controls movement

UserForm1.Show 'fire first userform
End Sub
```

Insert this into UserForm1 code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then UserForm2.TextBox1.Visible = True
    If UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value = True Then UserForm2.TextBox2.Visible = True
    If UserForm1.CheckBox3.Value = True Then UserForm2.TextBox3.Visible = True
    If UserForm1.CheckBox4.Value = True Then UserForm2.TextBox4.Visible = True
    UserForm2.Show

End Sub
```

You can also manipulate dimensions of controls and userform itself to determine appropriate sizes in accordance to how many options will be selected by user.

I did not iterate through these controls for sake of this example which you might want to do to be more efficient in terms of code.

Comment: Thank you @ AdamC, and will you tell me if there any site where I can refer to learn how to set dimensions of controls and userform, which will be really helpful and a must needed for my project for better look and feel... Thanks again

Comment: And i like to know whether this control help me to sort the fields based on their selection, for example it align the fields on the top if i select check box 3and4 or if i select 1and 3